# flatten a list of data frames and extract a variable

Tags: r

I have a mongo collection that I've flattened into a list of data frames. Something like this:

```
have <- list(
    structure(list(var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L), var3 = c(0.06, 0.05, 0.1), var1 = c("D", "B", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), 

    list(), 

    structure(list(var1 = c("A", "B", "C"), var2 = c(1L, 1L, 2L), var3 = c(0.08, 0.08, 0.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), 

    structure(list(var3 = c(0.05, 0.5, 0.01), var1 = c("B", "C", "D"), var4 = c("X", "Y", "Z"), var2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), 

    structure(list(var2 = c(0L, 0L), var3 = c(0.025, 0.1), var1 = c("A", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 

    structure(list(var3 = 0.05, var1 = "B", var2 = 0L), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)
)
```

Note that the second element is a list of length 0 and that the data frame dimensions vary. I want to extract `var1` and the list element order. For the list of length 0, I want to extract NA.

```
want <- data.frame(listID = seq(1:6), var1 = c("D, B, A", NA, "A, B, C", "B, C, D", "A, C", "B"))
want

#  listID    var1
#1      1 D, B, A
#2      2    <NA>
#3      3 A, B, C
#4      4 B, C, D
#5      5    A, C
#6      6       B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using purrr and dplyr's `na_if`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

have %>%
  map(pluck, "var1") %>%
  map_chr(paste, collapse = ", ") %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  data.frame(listID = 1:length(.), var1 = .)
#>   listID    var1
#> 1      1 D, B, A
#> 2      2    <NA>
#> 3      3 A, B, C
#> 4      4 B, C, D
#> 5      5    A, C
#> 6      6       B
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks @RyanFrost. i'm getting the error "Error in if (exact) { : argument is not interpretable as logical". `dplyr_0.8.5`, `purrr_0.3.4`

Comment: Could be dplyr - I'm on 1.0.0.

You can try upgrading or try replacing `na_if("")` with `ifelse(. == "", NA, .)`

Comment: ah, ok. jumping to 1.0 did the trick. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with base R:

```
out.var1 <- lapply(have, "[", "var1")
var1 <- sapply(out.var1, function(x) paste(t(x), collapse=", "))
var1[var1=="NULL"] <- NA
listID <- seq_len(length(out.var1))
(want <- data.frame(listID, var1))
#   listID    var1
# 1      1 D, B, A
# 2      2    <NA>
# 3      3 A, B, C
# 4      4 B, C, D
# 5      5    A, C
# 6      6       B
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(listID = seq_along(have), 
           var1 = vapply(have, function(x) toString(x[["var1"]]),
                  character(1L)))[var1 == "", var1 := NA_character_][]
#    listID    var1
# 1:      1 D, B, A
# 2:      2    <NA>
# 3:      3 A, B, C
# 4:      4 B, C, D
# 5:      5    A, C
# 6:      6       B
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R method using `sapply` :

```
var1 <- sapply(have, function(x) toString(x$var1))
data.frame(listID = seq_along(have), var1)

#  listID    var1
#1      1 D, B, A
#2      2        
#3      3 A, B, C
#4      4 B, C, D
#5      5    A, C
#6      6       B
```

You can replace empty value to `NA` if needed.